# tel: link for UK local phone

Tags: mobile

I'm struggling with the mobile friendly `href="tel:number"` link for UK number. Here is the situation:

In Lithuania we can tell the same telephone in local format `8 616 073 88` or in international way: `00370 616 073 88`. For both persons calling and receiving the phone is the same.

As I have tried with android chrome browser, the href="tel:861607388" version does not work, while `href="tel:0037061607388"` is working fine.

The problem:
I want to do the same link for a UK client's phone number `0845 070 5999`. I ask him to write me an international format, but he says that international format `0044 845` does not work or if it does it is incredibly expensive to call...

- Is it true that dialing UK number with international format is more expensive?
- If so, is there a way to correctly write tel: link with local format?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that dialing UK number with international format is more expensive?

**No**, as far as my experience goes, calling from `UK` to `UK` using the international format **will cost the same**.

> If so, is there a way to correctly write tel: link with local format?

**Yes, it's possible**. 
I would try to match `IP` to `Country` (with [Maxmind GeoIP2 Country Database](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-country-database)  or similar tool) and display the phone number accordingly.